# how do i create slider like instagram adjust slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-design

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NabBD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NabBD.jpg)

I wanna create a custom slider like this?

Comment: You can create a detailed question where your investigations must be refelected and it should ask the problems you are facing rather completely asking how to do that. 

I hope that will help you to edit your question as per need. thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a `PageView` widget with a controller with the `viewportFraction` property set to something like `0.2`. Then, have the `PageView`'s `children` property filled with `Container` widgets, each with a `height` of maybe `80` and `width` of maybe `2`. Then, wrap the `Container`s with `Padding` with the `padding` property set to `const EdgeInsets.symetric(horizontal: 10)`.

This should create that rough look. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i will try this approach later.